# After adding firewall rule, why did my Discord get the error "No Route"?

Tags: port-forwarding

I am trying to setup JIRA Software (Server) for use in my final year of uni. (We are at the point where they don't teach us how to set stuff up. We have to figure it out for ourselves.)

What I did was I opened port 8080 for TCP and UDP. (8080 is default for JIRA). After that, I set up a dynamic DNS so that I wouldn't have to give out a new URL every couple of weeks. After doing this, I tried to access JIRA on the URL. (http://public-ip:8080) as specified in the JIRA config. It didn't work. After going to the Atlassian forum, I was told maybe its the firewall.

> https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-I-host-JIRA-on-a-public-server/qaq-p/739981#U740058

I then added an inbound rule for port 8080 on the computer's firewall. After doing this, I could access JIRA from its URL but Discord stopped working. I could still browse the web but I could not use VOIP. On Discord, I got given the error:

> No Route

I tried restarting the modem but that did not fix the issue so I undid everything I did. The Dynamic DNS, the firewall rule and the port forwarding for 8080. That did not fix the issue. I had to hard reset the modem. To me adding one firewall rule shouldn't mess up everything else. Did I just miss a step or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad. You seem to assume that there is only a single way to do what you describe and that everybody understands what you exactly did based on your description. But, there is no generic firewall (depends on OS), there is no generic "open the port" (did you use command line, some GUI,... what exactly did you do). And given that web and VoIP still work there is also no "internet broke" but only a specific application does not work - whatever exactly this application needs to be working and maybe it did not even work before you made your unknown changes.

Comment: it was working as I was using the application before it broke. I use windows Firewall as am using windows 10.  I used the modem's gateway to open the ports. (GUI) At no point during the question did I say "internet broke" as I know that that is way to broad. That is why I used specific applications such as Skype and Discord.

Comment: *"At no point during the question did I say "internet broke" as I know that that is way to broad."* - it might be useful if you take a look at your post again which has the title *"After adding firewall rule, __My internet broke__, Why?"*

Comment: My bad. Have changed it now.

Comment: Still: *"After doing this, I could access JIRA from its URL __but my actual internet connection stopped__. I could still browse the web but I could use VOIP."*. And, the last sentence also (probably mistakenly)  claims that VoIP still works while your title says otherwise. Also, did you do some basic debugging of the problem by reverting the rules you've add selectively  to make it work again? If you did - which of the actions you did (router vs. local firewall) was the actual problem which broke it?

Comment: Yeh that was a mistake. VoIP didn't work. I added an inbound rule on the local firewall for port 8080. I deleted that rule after it did't work but the problem still persisted. I left the router firewall at normal, If I want to add rules I need to change it to user defined.

Comment: This sound like the problem is the rule you've added to your router then. Only, there is more than one router model and it is still unclear what exactly you did. Did you forward a single port or did you declare the host as exposed host (or DMZ or whatever they call it depending on the router)? And, was your VoIP application running on the same windows system or on a different system? Does it make a difference if you change the port (in case of port forwarding)? Also, if your question provides incorrect or incomplete information you should fix it instead of adding only a comment.